# How do I make this piece of Python code work?

Tags: python, variables, syntax-error

I am making a project, on Replit, that makes money, not in real life. I want the 'wheat_seads', 'melon_seeds', 'pumpkin_seeds', 'wheat', 'melon', 'pumpkin' to be available in and out of functions and be changed in different functions. I tried to put these variables in and out of the 'farm_command' to remove the 'Syntax error', but it doesn't work. If you can also, improve this piece of code...

```
from replit import db


#This function is when 'help' command is run
def help_command():
  print("So you need help...")
  print("I am happy to help!")

  print("1. 'help'")
  print("2. 'farm'")
  print("3. 'harvest'")

#This functon is when 'farm' command is run
def farm_command():
  global wheat_seeds = 1
  global melon_seeds = 1
  global pumpkin_seeds = 1
  global wheat = 0
  global melon = 0
  global pumpkin = 0

  
  print("What seed do you want to farm?")
  farm_seed = input("Seed: ")
  farm_seed = farm_seed.lower()

  if farm_seed == "wheat_seeds":
    print("You planted " + wheat_seeds + " wheat seed/s")
    wheat_seeds -= wheat_seeds
    
    
  


#The user's cash amount
db["User"] = {
  "wallet":0,
  "bank":0
}

#This is the users inventory
inventory = [wheat_seeds, melon_seeds, pumpkin_seeds, wheat, melon, pumpkin]

#This is prompted to ask the user what command should be run
command = input("Command: ")

#This checks which command is inputted and runs the respective command
if command == "help":
  help_command()
elif command == "farm":
  farm_command()
```

Comment: Please add the text of SyntaxError to your post

Comment: @Expurple   `global wheat_seeds = 1` is the syntax error, but there are many more issues with the code unfortunately.

Comment: Currently, people who want to help you need to guess what the error is, or download and run your code. I would be easier to just look at the error. Please, paste the full error text, like in this post for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447672/rpy2-parsing-error-while-opening-external-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign a value directly when you defining a global variable.
Try it like this:

global wheat_seeds 
wheat_seeds = 1 
and so on...